# Magento2 400 Bad Request for Get Product with Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter, magento2, magento-2.3

I am trying to load test the checkout process for the Magento 2 API using JMeter.  We are expecting 1000 concurrent users.

The following curl command works fine:

```
curl -g -X GET "https:/oursite.com/rest/V1/products/25006A/" -H "Authorization: Bearer tm2yd2908exmy0ntoq9esvr5gqoh7upp"
```

However when I put in the same Authorization Bearer in the header for JMeter to the same URL it does not return the JSON.  Instead it throws a 400 Bad Request.  What other headers do I need?

Here is what I have for JMeter script:

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Get Products" enabled="true">
  <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
  </elementProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${varDomain}</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/rest/V1/products/25006A/</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
  <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
</HTTPSamplerProxy>
<hashTree>
  <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
      <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
        <stringProp name="Header.name">Authorization Bearer</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Header.value">${varToken}</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
        <stringProp name="Header.name">content-type</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Header.value">application/json</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
    </collectionProp>
  </HeaderManager>
  <hashTree/>
</hashTree>
```

Comment: Show how did you added in JMeter

Comment: I edited the question to include the JMeter for the Get Products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/) there is a possibility to create a JMeter Test Plan from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) command

1. From JMeter's main menu choose  `Tools -> Import from cURL`
2. Use the following command:

   ```
   curl "https:/oursite.com/rest/V1/products/25006A/" -H "Authorization: Bearer tm2yd2908exmy0ntoq9esvr5gqoh7upp"
   ```
3. That's it, JMeter will generate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) with correct values

   [image]

---

The problem with your script is that the header name should be [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) and header value should be `Bearer tm2yd2908exmy0ntoq9esvr5gqoh7upp`

Answer (score 1):

Try and add `view results tree` listener and see what response message says. Usually that tells you what is wrong with the request.

If I had to guess it is `content-type` or `Accept` header which you need to set to application/json.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your header name should be `Authorization` **only**

Put `Bearer ${varToken}` as the **value** in header